# Listen when connectivity lost on Android

Tags: android, connection, network-connection

How can I know and listen when my device hasn't **connectivity**?
Yes, I know that with broadcast and listen for change status of connection, but my problem is that I would know costantly if my device can reach my webserver.
I've developed my **BroadcastReceiver** with a function:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (networkInfo != null && (networkInfo.isConnected() || networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())) {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
```

But **It doesn't assure me that my server is reachable** because I can have a wifi or mobile data, but not access to web.

I have developed a function that check if connectivity is ok:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) App.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
      try {
         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
         URL url = new URL(ConfigData.CHECK_IP);   // Change to "http://google.com" for www  test.
         HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         urlc.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT_CALL);
         urlc.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT_CALL);
         if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {        // 200 = "OK" code (http connection is fine).
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                return  false;
            }
            catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

But How Can I listen constantly if I have connectivity and launch event when my device cant reach my server?
I read that create a service that ping constantly is not recommended so, are there other ways?

Comment: "I read that create a service that ping constantly is not recommended" -- correct. "are there other ways?" -- by definition, no. The only way to know if you can talk to your server is to talk to your server.

Comment: Hello, thankyou, so my unique method is create service  (or websocket) that ping costantly my server? :(

Comment: My recommendation is to not bother. Unless you have real data to send, do not try connecting to the server. *If* you have real data to send, *and* you have problems connecting to the server at that point, *then* implement an retry policy with exponential-backoff. Or, switch to a push-based system using FCM.

Comment: no matter your checks, you won't be able to anticipate if anybody has chainsawed a submarine fiberoptic cable, so just implement a decent notification / retry scheme

Comment: Hello thank you! yes I have always retrieve and send data from server, because this App needs internet connection to work. I used Volley library for send data and it Has a "setRetryPolicy" maybe I can use this?